# Unexpected character encountered while parsing API response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am getting this exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
>         HResult=0x80131500
>         Message=Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'outputObject.address', line 17, position 16.

when deserializing the response data from an API.
(complete exception on the end of the post)

**CODE**

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(webResponseEntity.ResponseData, typeof(CarLookupResponse)) as CarLookupResponse;
```

**MODEL**

```
   public class CarLookupResponse : ICarLookupResponse
    {
        public ICarLookupResult Result { get; set; }

        public ICarLookupOutputObject OutputObject { get; set; }

        public CarLookupResponse()
        {
            Result = new CarLookupResult();
            OutputObject = new CarLookupOutputObject();
        }
    }
```

Folowing is the output object interface
 **OutputObject Interface**

```
public interface ICarLookupOutputObject 
    {
        int  CarId { get; set; }

        string CartestId { get; set; }

        int[] ModelYears { get; set; }

        string FirstName { get; set; }

        string LastName { get; set; }

        string Email { get; set; }

        string SSN { get; set; }

        string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

**JSON**

```
   {
     "result": {
        "id": 1,
        "value": "lookup successful.",
        "error": null
      },
      "outputObject": {
        "CarId": 2025,
        "CartestId": "testing-02",
        "ModelYears": [
          2017,
          2018
        ],
        "firstName": "Troy",
        "lastName": "Aaster",
        "email": "testuser@gmail.com",
        "address": {
          "apartment": "",
          "state": "CA",
          "city": "BRISBANE",
          "zipCode": "94005",
          "streetAddress": "785, SPITZ BLVD"
        },
        "ssn": "511-04-6666"
      }
    }
```

I tried to find the reason for this exception but couldn't get it, **JSON** is valid, I have checked that.

Following is the full exception deatials

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
>         HResult=0x80131500
>         Message=Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'outputObject.address', line 17, position 16.
>         Source=Newtonsoft.Json
>         StackTrace:
>          at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(ReadType readType)
>          at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()
>          at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
>          at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
>          at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
>          at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
>          at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
>          at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
>          at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
>          at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
>          at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)

Comment: Perhaps the c# property to which `outputObject.address` is bound is a string, not a complex object?

Comment: @dbc Yes address is a string

Comment: Without `CarLookupOutputObject` I cannot say for sure, but since the exception is getting thrown from `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()` it's likely that `CarLookupOutputObject.Address` is a string not an object, which would account for the exception.

Comment: @dbc Yes its a string i have edited my question with the same , please check

Comment: @dbc is this happening because the address is a string?

Comment: Yes that's it exactly.  A JSON object such as `{ "CarId": 2025 }` cannot be deserialized into a primitive string.  See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#Objects

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was obvious but sometimes it gets difficult to identify its obvious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is that you have declared `CarLookupOutputObject.Address` to be a `string`, but the corresponding JSON value is an object:

```
"address": {
  "apartment": "",
  ...
},
```

As explained in its [Serialization Guide](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm), only primitive .Net types and types convertible to `string` are serialized as JSON strings.  Since the value of `"address"` is not primitive, the exception is thrown.

Instead, modify your data model as follows, as suggested by http://json2csharp.com/:

```
public class CarLookupOutputObject 
{
    public Address address { get; set; }

    // Remainder unchanged
}

public class Address
{
    public string apartment { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string zipCode { get; set; }
    public string streetAddress { get; set; }
}
```