# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {

Tags: serialization, json.net

I am trying to parse some JSON with `Newtonsoft.JSON.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` - in fact the JSON was also generated by Newtonsoft from the same classes I am trying to deserialize into, and is definitely valid.

But it is giving me the exception: `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {.`

I've made a very simplified example to show the problem.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "address": {
    "country": {
      "name": "UK"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a simplified model which still shows the problem:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public Address Address;
}

public class Address
{
    public Country Country;

    public Address(string country)
    {
    }
}

public class Country
{
    public string Name;
}
```

Here is the code which fails:

```cs
// Fails with Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : "Unexpected character encountered
// while parsing value: {. Path 'address.country', line 3, position 16."
Person item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
```

---

I have checked, and this is not the same problem as [C# - Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '[0].Statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53562566) or [Unexpected character encountered while parsing API response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51925160) . I have now worked out the issue (see my answer below), and it is NOT the same problem or solution as either of those two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This short answer is, make sure that the class corresponding to the immediate parent of the path where the problem is reported (the path is `'address.country'` in the above exception message; its immediate parent is `'address'`) has a public parameterless constructor.

So, in the above you must add a public parameterless constructor to your `Address` class.

---

Here is the `Address` class from the example with some comments explaining what is going on:

```cs
public class Address
{
    public Country Country;

    // With this present the JSON parses just fine!
    public Address() { }

    // Because both of the following were true:
    //  1) the name of a parameter here matches the name of a field to be populated and
    //  2) there was no public parameterless constructor
    // this was constraining what could appear in the JSON to populate "address"!
    public Address(string country)
    {
    }
}
```